# Add to existing hash inside of a class ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a hash that has a data structure like so:

```
hash = { 
:a => { :a1 => "x", :a2: => "x", :a3 => "x" },
:b => { :b1 => "x", :b2: => "x", :b3 => "x" },    
 }
```

Inside of a class function. I am rather new to OO, so maybe I'm not understanding the variable scoping correctly.

Here is my code:

```
class Foo
  # Control class args
  attr_accessor :site, :dir

  # Initiate our class variables
  def initialize(site,dir)
    @site    = site
    @dir = dir
    #@records = {}
    @records = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new }
  end

  def grab_from_it
    line = %x[tail -1 #{@dir}/#{@site}/log].split(" ")
    time = line[0, 5].join(" ")
    rc   = line[6]
    host = line[8]
    ip   = line[10]
    file = line[12]

    @records = { "#{file}" => { :time => "#{time}", :rc => "#{rc}", :host => "#{host}", :ip => "#{ip}" } }
  end

end
```

Main body:

```
foo = Foo.new(site,dir)

foo.grab_from_it

pp foo

sleep(10)

foo.grab_from_it

pp foo
```

It works and successfully creates a hash with my desired structure, but when I run again, it  overwrites the existing hash. I want it to keep adding to it, so I can create a "running tab".

Comment: What exactly would you like add to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line

```rb
@records = { "#{file}" => { :time => "#{time}", :rc => "#{rc}", :host => "#{host}", :ip => "#{ip}" } }
```

with

```rb
@records["#{file}"] = { :time => "#{time}", :rc => "#{rc}", :host => "#{host}", :ip => "#{ip}" }
```

Every time you call `@records = {}` the instance variable points to a new hash. Thus the initialization code in `initialize` has no effect. Rather than replace the initialized hash with a new one, you should add new entry to the existing hash, using the `[]=` instance method of `Hash`.

BTW, you can use `variable` to refer to the string rather than creating a new one using string interpolation `"#{variable}"`.

```rb
@records[file] = { :time => time, :rc => rc, :host => host, :ip => ip }
```

If you want the *UPDATE* behavior for both the first and the second layers of the hash, you can take a look at the [`Hash#update`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) method.

```rb
@records[file].update({ :time => time, :rc => rc, :host => host, :ip => ip })
```